# What separates a transformer from a reducer ? - Clojure

Tags: clojure, transform, reducers

From what I gather a transformer is the use of functions that change , alter , a collection of elements . Like if I did added 1 to each element in a collection of

```
[1 2 3 4 5]
```

and it became

```
[2 3 4 5 6]
```

but writing the code for this looks like

```
(map inc)
```

but I keep getting this sort of code confused with a reducer. Because it produces a new accumulated result .

The question I ask is , what is the difference between a transformer and a reducer ?

Comment: What reducer code are you confusing with `(map inc)`?

Comment: Could it be your confusing trans*ducers* with transformers?

Comment: ‘Transformer’ is not a technical term in Clojure as far as I know. I believe *transducers* where called ‘reducing function *transformers*’ in an early iteration of the transducers feature, but no more.

Comment: https://www.braveclojure.com/quests/reducers/know-your-reducers/ might help

Comment: Long ago, hiredman wrote [an article](https://ce2144dc-f7c9-4f54-8fb6-7321a4c318db.s3.amazonaws.com/reducers.html) explaining reducers and how they are transformed, which I have found useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely just confusing various nomenclature (as the comments above suggest), but I'll answer what I think is your question by taking some liberties in interpreting what you mean to be reducer and transformer.

**Reducing:**

A reducing function (what you probably think is a reducer), is a function that takes an accumulated value and a current value, and returns a new accumulated value.

```
(accumulated, current) => accumulated
```

These functions are passed to reduce, and they successively step through a sequence performing whatever the body of the reducing function says with it's two arguments (accumulated and current), and then returning a new accumulated value which will be used as the accumulated value (first argument) to the next call of the reducing function.

For example, plus can be viewed as a reducing function.

```
(reduce + [0 1 2]) => 3
```

First, the reducing function (plus in this example) is called with 0 and 1, which returns 1.  On the next call, 1 is now the accumulated value, and 2 is the current value, so plus is called with 1 and 2, returning 3, which completes the reduction as there are no further elements in the collection to process.

It may help to look at a simplified version of a reduce implementation:

```
(defn reduce1
  ([f coll] ;; f is a reducing function
      (let [[x y & xs] coll]
           ;; called with the accumulated value so far "x"
           ;; and cur value in input sequence "y"
           (if y (reduce1 f (cons (f x y) xs)) 
               x)))
  ([f start coll]
      (reduce1 f (cons start coll))))
```

You can see that the function "f" , or the "reducing function" is called on each iteration with two arguments, the accumulated value so far, and the next value in the input sequence.  The return value of this function is used as the first argument in the next call, etc. and thus has the type:

`(x, y) => x`

**Transforming:**

A transformation, the way I think you mean it, suggests the shape of the input does not change, but is simply modified according to an arbitrary function.  This would be functions you pass to map, as they are applied to each element and build up a new collection of the same shape, but with that function applied to each element.

```
(map inc [0 1 2]) => '(1 2 3)
```

Notice the shape is the same, it's still a 3 element sequence, whereas in the reduction above, you input a 3 element sequence and get back an integer.  Reductions can change the shape of the final result, map does not.

Note that I say the "shape" doesn't change, but the type of each element may change depending on what your "transforming" function does:

```
(map #(list (inc %)) [0 1 2]) => '((1) (2) (3))
```

It's still a 3 element sequence, but now each element is a list, not an integer.

**Addendum:**

There are two related concepts in Clojure, Reducers and Transducers, which I just wanted to mention since you asked about reducers (which have as specific meaning in Clojure) and transformers (which are the names Clojurists typically assign to a transducing function via the shorthand "xf").  It would turn this already long answer into a short-story if I tried to explain the details of both here, and it's been done better than I can do by others:

Transducers: 
http://elbenshira.com/blog/understanding-transducers/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mTbuzafcII

Reducers and Transducers:
https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2017/reducers-transducers-and-coreasync-in-clojure/

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that many transformations of collections can be expressed in terms of reduce. For instance map could be implemented as

```
(defn map [f coll] (reduce (fn [x y] (conj x (f y))) [] [0 1 2 3 4]))
```

and then you would call

```
(map inc [1 2 3 4 5])
```

to obtain

```
[2 3 4 5 6]
```

In our homemade implementation of map, the function that we pass to reduce is

```
(fn [x y] (conj x (f y))))
```

where f is the function that we would like to apply to every element. So we can write a function that produces such a function for us, passing the function that we would like to map.

```
(defn mapping-with-conj [f] (fn [x y] (conj x (f y))))
```

But we still see the presence of conj in the above function assuming we want to add elements to a collection. We can get even more flexibility by extra indirection:

```
(defn mapping [f] (fn [step] (fn [x y] (step x (f y)))))
```

Then we can use it like this:

```
(def increase-by-1 (mapping inc))
(reduce (increase-by-1 conj) [] [1 2 3])
```

The `(map inc)` you are referring does what our call to `(mapping inc)` does. Why would you want to do things this way? The answer is that it gives us a lot of flexibility to build things. For instance, instead of building up a collection, we can do

```
(reduce ((map inc) +) 0 [1 2 3 4 5])
```

Which will give us the sum of the mapped collection [2 3 4 5 6]. Or we can add extra processing steps just by simple function composition.

```
(reduce ((comp (filter odd?) (map inc)) conj) [] [1 2 3 4 5])
```

which will first remove even elements from the collection before we map. The `transduce` function in Clojure does essentially what the above line does, but takes care of another few extra details, too. So you would actually write

```
(transduce (comp (filter odd?) (map inc)) conj [] [1 2 3 4 5])
```

*To sum up*, the `map` function in Clojure has two arities. Calling it like `(map inc [1 2 3 4 5])` will map every element of a collection so that you obtain `[2 3 4 5 6]`. Calling it just like `(map inc)` gives us a function that behaves pretty much like our `mapping` function in the above explanation.